# Stacked bar graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble writing a code that produces a stacked bar chart where the  "total" value for the bar is the sum of the values in my data frame. For example, I have my data in the following format:

```
amount    types years
7753547  Funding  2015
7370817  Funding  2016
4140110 Expenses  2015
4209865 Expenses  2016
```

I really want a stacked bar chart where the x-axis is the year, fill is by types, and the "total" is the funding amount and the bar is partitioned by expenses. So, for example, in 2015, the bar goes up to 7.7 million and then is partitioned off at 4.14 million. Any suggestions would be great. I've been attempting to find some code but to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: I think your description of what you want is a bit contradictory. If the top of each bar is just the value of the `Funding` row for that year, then you don't really want the sum of the values, you want the values represented as they currently are without summing. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi, Marius. Sorry for the very poor description--I have the image in my head but am having trouble describing it. When I run my code right now, the bar's total is 7.7 million + 4.14 million. However, I need the peak of the bar to be 7.7 million and for the bar to be cut up at 4.14 million. Basically, I want to show how much was funded and how much of that funding was spent. Does this help a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to keep the values as they are, you can use `position = "identity"`. This may not work if sometimes expenses are greater than funding, but is probably the simplest solution for your current example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(years), y = amount, fill = types)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    geom_bar(position = "identity", stat = "identity")
```

To reassure yourself that this is reflecting the correct data, see this modification that puts `Expenses` fully inside the larger `Funding` bar:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(years), y = amount, fill = types))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    geom_bar(data = df[df$types == "Funding", ], position = "identity", stat = "identity",
             width = 0.9, colour = "black") +
    geom_bar(data = df[df$types == "Expenses", ], position = "identity", stat = "identity",
             width = 0.8, colour = "black")
```

Comment: @user122514, either this or you will need to modify your data.

Comment: Thank you, Marius. I've actually tried something very similar to your code, but for some reason, the cutoff for Expenses seems to be bigger than Funding. This doesn't make sense in my case, since the Funding amount is clearly bigger. http://imgur.com/a/n6kfa

Comment: That image looks right to me, unless I am missing something. Expenses are in red and go up to ~ 4 million as they are in the data. Funding continues up to ~ 8 million (technically the funding bar starts from 0, but the first half of the bar is covered by Expenses).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. This is exactly what I needed. I guess that's what happens when you only get four hours of sleep the night before! Thanks so much. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=years, y = amount, fill =types))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I had the exact same code, but it's not giving me what I want. I need the "total" to be 7.7 million, not 7.7 + 4.14 million.

Comment: When I run this code, the bar's total is 7.7 million + 4.14 million. However, I need the peak of the bar to be 7.7 million and for the bar to be cut up at 4.14 million. Basically, I want to show how much was funded and how much of that funding was spent. Hopefully that clarifies some stuff.

Comment: 4.14 is your `Expenses` and the remaining is `Funding` then?

Comment: Yup. So, what I have in mind is having the Expenses portion in your graph to be "inside" the Funding portion, since that would indicate how much of the funding was actually spent.